# Overloaded Circle() is ambiguous in C++ Circle Class

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to create a circle class in C++ but when I compile I get an error saying "call of overloaded 'Circle' is ambiguous. I am quite new to C++ and not sure what this means. I have been using a similar example found here [Class tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double pi = 3.14159265;

class Circle
{
    private:
            double radius, xpos, ypos, area;

    public:
            Circle(double r, double xposition, double yposition) {
                r = radius;
                xposition = xpos;
                yposition = ypos;
            }

            Circle(double r = 0) {
                radius = r;
                xpos = 0;
                ypos = 0;
            } 

            Circle() {
                radius = 0;
                xpos = 0;
                ypos = 0;
            }

            double getRadius() {return radius;}
            double getX() {return xpos;}
            double getY() {return ypos;}
            double getArea() {return pi*radius*radius;}

            Circle operator+(const Circle& c) {
                Circle circle;
                circle.area = this -> getArea() + c.getArea();
                return circle;
            } 
};


int main()
{
    Circle circ(3,2,1);
    double x = circ.getX();
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A constructor with all default arguments can also act as a default-constructor when called with zero arguments. So it looks like you wrote two default-constructors, which is why they re ambiguous.

Comment: BTW `r = radius` should be `radius = r` (same goes for the other assignments).

Comment: @0x499602D2: Or using member initializers would be an even better idea. They would fail to compile if you got them backwards.

Comment: @FredLarson Certainly.

Comment: You should implement `operator+` as a free function in terms of `operator+=`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
Circle(double r = 0);
Circle();
```

Nothing much more to say about it that isn't already obvious from the above.

The default value in `Circle(double r = 0)` makes the use of `Circle()` ambiguous.

---

By the way, you've got your member variable initialization all wrong here:

```
Circle(double r, double xposition, double yposition)
{
    r = radius;
    xposition = xpos;
    yposition = ypos;
}
```

Instead of setting the member variables to the values of the input arguments, you are setting the input arguments to the "junk" values of the member variables...

Comment: In fact, this could be done with only the three-argument constructor. Just default all the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different constructors that can be called with no parameters, because one of them has a default for the parameter. You can delete the default constructor, since it's redundant.